# iPhone: UITableView not Displaying New Data After Call to reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My problem is that the cell.textLabel does not display the new data following a reload. I can see the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called so I know the `reloadData` call goes thru. If I log the `rowString` I see the correct value so the string I set label text to is correct.  What am I doing wrong?

I have following code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    static NSString *RowListCellIdentifier = @"RowListCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RowListCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RowListCellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    NSMutableString *rowString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [rowString appendString:[[[rows objectAtIndex:row] firstNumber]stringValue]];
    [rowString appendString:@" : "];
    [rowString appendString:[[[rows objectAtIndex:row] secondNumber]stringValue]];
    [rowString appendString:@" : "];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:rowString];

    [rowString release];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`cell.textLabel.text = $VALUE;`

if it doesnt help, are you sure that you have set the tableView.delegate AND the tableView.dataSource?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. He just using the old style reference.

Comment: Yes i am sure because the table shows the data so the connection must be ok right?

Comment: actually it was the delegates and the datasource which was messed up, thx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

What you have now is an unusual construction and might be preventing updates to the UI. In methods that set up a view, you want to call the superclass method before the subclass operations. You reverse the order in methods that tears down a view. You usually don't have to call the viewWillAppear of the super unless you have a custom superclass.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried it but it did not make any difference on the update problem.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is viewWillAppear the only place you call reloadData? If so, then your table will only update after the table is removed from view and then displayed again.

Comment: Yes and that's exactly what i do. I go into the detail view, change data then pop view which causes the viewWillAppear to fire and reloadData and i am logging the data to console and i know data is ok but still not visible in the UI

Comment: You only need to call reload data when the data changes while the table is displayed. The table will automatically load itself when it first appears so the reload data you have now is redundant.

Comment: Try logging cell.textLabel.text right after you set it to see what value it has. That might help you narrow things down. Where (what line) did you log rowString?

Comment: I have been doing a NSLog of rowString just before [rowString release] and data looks correct.

Comment: I'll try that out and get back with the results

Comment: I added following just before return cell and data looks fine:
NSLog(@"%@",[cell.textLabel text]);
NSLog(@"%@", rowString);

this is very weird, now spend 2 days on this

Comment: I'm stumped. The code you have posted is correct. If the cell.textLabel.text is showing as correct and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called when it should be, then you've got a very strange problem. The only thing I can think is that somehow, you not populating the correct instance of UITableView. You might try logging the address of the table sent to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and make sure it is the correct table. When all else fails log everything including the indexPath at the start and the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your `cell.textLabel` is somehow being reset to nil. In my experience I find it easiest to treat the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as if it's always creating a new cell. Even when it's reusing a cell I want to be ready for everything.

The Header file for `cell.textLabel` state that the default value is nil. This means that you want to assign a label to the textLabel before you go about changing it's text property.

To do that, replace:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:rowString];
```

with:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];//or initWithFrame:
label.text = rowString;
/* Insert your own customization here */
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel = label;
[label release];
```